# Problems loading images in Front End environment

Tags: javascript, express, webpack, ejs

I'm trying to get an image to load up properly on my main page, but for some reason it keeps giving me an error.

Here is the HTML I'm using for it currently

```
<section class="about-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque gravida neque elit, vel gravida nibh hendrerit eget. Integer pharetra risus in lorem luctus, vitae porta neque lobortis. Sed vel laoreet ante, sed porttitor risus. Pellentesque tincidunt imperdiet ante sit amet aliquet. Etiam non ligula id diam hendrerit venenatis. Sed accumsan in mi eu pulvinar. Mauris vel fermentum quam.</p>
        </div>
        <img src="./../../images/armoryabout.png" alt="Images of Conan Bases">
    </div>
</section>
```

[image: Error Image]

I am running a bit of a custom environment using Express, EJS, and Webpack (I plan on using React for a feature) so I'll include the code for those as well.

server.js

```
const path = require( 'path' );
const express = require( 'express' );
const webpack = require( 'webpack' );
const webpackDevMiddleware = require( 'webpack-dev-middleware' );
const expressLayouts = require( 'express-ejs-layouts' );

const app = express();
const config = require( './webpack.config.js' );
const compiler = webpack( config );

// Tell express to use the webpack-dev-middleware and use the webpack.config.js
// configuration file as a base.
app.use( webpackDevMiddleware( compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    noInfo: true
} ) );

app.use( require( "webpack-hot-middleware" )(compiler) );

app.set( 'views', path.join( __dirname, './src/views/' ) );
app.use( express.static( './dist/' ) );
//app.set( 'layout', './src/views/layout.ejs' );
app.set( 'view engine', 'ejs' );
app.use( expressLayouts );

app.get( '/', ( req, res ) => {
    res.render( 'pages/index' );
} );

app.get( '/armory', ( req, res ) => {
    res.render( 'pages/armory' );
} );

// Serve the files on port 3000.
app.listen( 3000, function() {
    console.log( 'Example app listening on port 3000!\n' );
} );
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require( 'path' );
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require( 'html-webpack-plugin' );
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require( 'clean-webpack-plugin' );
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlCriticalWebpackPlugin = require( 'html-critical-webpack-plugin' );

const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const isDev = mode === "development";

let config = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: [
        './src/scripts/app.js',
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client'
    ],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        host: '192.168.1.122'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin( {
            cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false
        } ),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin( {
            filename: 'styles.css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].css'
        } ),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin( {
            template: './src/views/pages/index.ejs',
            filename: 'index.html',
            inject: true,
            excludeChunks: [ 'server' ]
        } ),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin( {
            template: './src/views/pages/armory.ejs',
            filename: 'armory.html',
            inject: true,
            excludeChunks: [ 'server' ]
        } ),
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist' ),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.ejs$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'ejs-loader', // I have a suspicion this could be causing my issue
                        options: {
                            esModule: false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    'html-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: [
                    isDev ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    isDev ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|gif|webp)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            outputPath: 'images',
                            name: '[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                        options: {
                            bypassOnDebug: true,
                            disable: true
                        }
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
    }
};

!isDev ? config.plugins.push(
    new HtmlCriticalWebpackPlugin( {
        base: path.join(path.resolve( __dirname), './dist'),
        src: 'index.html',
        dest: 'index.html',
        inline: true,
        minify: true,
        extract: true,
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
        penthouse: {
            blockJSRequests: false
        }
    } )
) : null;

module.exports = config;
```

I was wondering if anyone knows what my problem here is?

Answer (score 0):

There should be another `express.static` pointing to `images` directory:

```
app.use( express.static( '/path/to/images/' ) );
```

Comment: I've tried this out, but I seem to be having the same issue.
I used
`app.use( express.static( '/src/images/' ) );`
as well as
`app.use( express.static( '/images/' ) );`

I feel it might be an issue with how I'm using Webpack possibly?

Answer (score 0):

So since I'm using Webpack middleware to serve my files from memory I had to point Express to my ./src/ folder instead of my ./dist/ folder. This way it serves up any assets I need in my EJS templates.

```
app.set( 'views', path.join( __dirname, './src/views/' ) );
//app.use( express.static( './dist/' ) ); - Wrong
app.use( express.static( 'src' ); - Correct
app.set( 'view engine', 'ejs' );
app.use( expressLayouts );
```